# Repeating Forms and Finding List of Repeating Forms in REDCap - Is there a section in REDCap that lists all repeating forms?

Tags: redcap

I am working with a large REDCap database that has over 30 forms. Does REDCap list which of the many forms are repeating forms in a specific place (i.e., is there a place in REDCap that identifies what all of the repeating forms in your project are)? For example, one can find the page name of the instrument in the codebook (it's usually the name of the instrument with underscores in between each word).

One can also find the Unique Event Name of an instrument in the "Define My Events" section of REDCap. Is there a section in REDCap that lists the names of all of your repeating instruments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually figured this out. You would navigate to your project's home page and click on "Project Setup" on the left panel. On this page, you would scroll down until you see the "Enable optional modules and customizations" section of your module. Find "Repeating instruments and events". Click on the "Modify" button to the left of it. From there, you will be able to see the settings of all of your instruments in each arm and whether or not any of them are repeating instruments. Be sure not to save any changes you may accidentally make while scrolling through the "Repeating instruments and events" settings, especially if you have a live project.

Comment: Furthermore, looking at the record status dashboard will visually indicate the instruments (or events) that are repeating as their status icon will have a + button. Lastly, running a report or exporting data will include a column `redcap_repeat_instrument` and `repeat_instance`, indicating that the row pertains to a repeating instrument and which instance it is.